# Vectorize digits arg to format() in R

Tags: r

I'd like to format a vector of numbers with a dynamic number of digits, as specified in another vector. `format` only uses the first element of the `digits` vector though. Is there any way to vectorize this?

Example:

```
format(c(0.15, 0.43), digits=c(1, 2)) 
# [1] "0.1" "0.4" 
# Expected: c("0.1", "0.43")
```

Comment: You could use `mapply` ie. `mapply(format, c(0.15, 0.43), digits=c(1,2))#[1] "0.1"  "0.43"` though I am not sure if this is what you wanted.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `format()`, you could do it with `sprintf()`

```
sprintf("%2$.*1$g", c(1, 2), c(0.15, 0.43))
# [1] "0.1"  "0.43"
```

This is based on one of the examples shown in `?sprintf`

```
n <- 1:6
## Asterisk and argument re-use, 'e' example reiterated:
sprintf("e with %1$2d digits = %2$.*1$g", n, exp(1))
# [1] "e with  1 digits = 3"       "e with  2 digits = 2.7"    
# [3] "e with  3 digits = 2.72"    "e with  4 digits = 2.718"  
# [5] "e with  5 digits = 2.7183"  "e with  6 digits = 2.71828"
```

Answer (score 0):

Per akrun:

```
mapply(format, c(0.15, 0.43), digits=c(1,2))
#[1] "0.1" "0.43"
```

While this is probably slower than Richard Scriven's `sprintf` recommendation, it works better for me because I'm using other parts of `format` less suitable to `sprintf`, like the thousands separator.